# Some help with my user testing process

Tags: usability, testing

I'm creating a document for testing out a website that our company is launching within the next few weeks. The development is outsourced but the design is done in-house. Recently

I've introduced UX/usability to the company and they've asked me to put together a document outlining how I would evaluate the UX of future websites we are launching. They want all of the testing to be done in-house so this is what I've come up with to complete this. What I want to know is this a good way to go about it? Should I change, add in or omit anything? Just some general comments would be appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ylfq0d79ikqmz2/Phase%20One.odt?dl=0

Comment: I'm not sure that we can offer reviews for documents like this - As you could remove your document at any time, this site could potentially be left with a broken link which would render this question useless to anyone else seeking help on a similar matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things what I'm missing in your document:

Write a paragraph for your introduction to your user, explaining why you're doing this, what you expect (rules for the type of test you're doing, that you're not testing the user but whatever he is testing) and with what goal in mind.

I see you're checking if whatever is being said or done matches your pre-defined heuristics and checkboxes. I think it's easier for both you and your participant to define clear flows you want to test. Describe what your user's goals and tasks are for the test and write everything down about what he does and how he does it within the context. This will give you far more valuable insight than having to check if whatever is happening falls within your guidelines. This also gives you the chance to test if you're matching the expectations and if your customer journeys make sense.

It will be very difficult to test and for a user to fill in questions like 'Important and repetitive actions feel effortless and aren’t unnecessarily complicated'. It will however be testable if you write scenario's where you force the user to perform the same actions and to write down what they think and do.

Ask questions during the test, like 'what do you think this site is about' after they first see it. Try not to influence their train of thought, but do ask questions where they have to explain what something does before they click or where they think they can find something.

Edit: What I wrote applies to many types of usability tests. Personally I'm rather fond of the think and talk aloud test because you can simulate actual usage.

Comment: Glad I could help :)